# Find all possible ways to split a list of elements into a a given number of group of the same size

Tags: r

I have a list of elements and I want an object that gives me all possible ways of splitting these elements into a given number of groups of the same size.

For example here is my list:

```
MyElements <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

And I want all possible combinations of spliting them into 2 groups:

```
nb.groups <- 2
```

The answer might for example be of that kind:

```
[[1]]

[1] 1,2

[2] 3,4

[[2]]

[1] 1,3

[2] 2,4

[[3]]

[1] 2,3

[2] 1,4
```

I want to avoid the repetition of that kind:

```
[[1]]

[1] 1,2

[2] 3,4

[[2]]

[1] 3,4

[2] 1,2
```

Thanks a lot !

Thank you for answering. I think I should give you more informations about what I'm trying to achieve.

the list (or vector because obviously MyElements was a vector) is actually ID numbers for individuals. I want a list of all possible ways of splitting these individuals in a desired number of groups which all have the same size.

If I'm not mistaken the only solution which actually works for the moment is the so-called brute-force-and-dirty solution from Juba. But as Juba said, it gets quickly (way too quickly for my purposes !) unusable.

Thanks again

Comment: Your "list" is actually a `vector`.

Comment: Is `(1,2,3,4)` and `(1,2,4,3)` desirable?

Comment: This sort of confusion between permutations and combinations seems to be popping up a lot recently.  It looks like you want combinations, *not* perms, in which case I think Juba's answer is appropriate.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Maybe my answer is appropriate, but it's almost unusable (computationaly speaking). There are surely far better and far more elegant algorithms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following recursive logic allows you to calculate all combinations without repetitions and without the need to calculate all of them first. It works pretty nice, as long as choose(nx-1,ning-1) returns an integer. If it doesn't, calculating the possibilities is a bit ridiculous.

It's a recursive process, so it might take long and it will cause memory trouble when your vectors exceed a certain limit. But then again, dividing a set of 14 elements in 7 groups gives already 135135 unique possibilities. Things get out of hand pretty quick in these kind of things.

The logic in pseudo-something (wouldn't call it pseudocode)

```
nb = number of groups
ning = number of elements in every group
if(nb == 2)
   1. take first element, and add it to every possible 
       combination of ning-1 elements of x[-1] 
   2. make the difference for each group defined in step 1 and x 
       to get the related second group
   3. combine the groups from step 2 with the related groups from step 1

if(nb > 2)
   1. take first element, and add it to every possible 
       combination of ning-1 elements of x[-1] 
   2. to define the other groups belonging to the first groups obtained like this, 
       apply the algorithm on the other elements of x, but for nb-1 groups
   3. combine all possible other groups from step 2 
       with the related first groups from step 1
```

Translating this to R gives us :

```
perm.groups <- function(x,n){
    nx <- length(x)
    ning <- nx/n

    group1 <- 
      rbind(
        matrix(rep(x[1],choose(nx-1,ning-1)),nrow=1),
        combn(x[-1],ning-1)
      )
    ng <- ncol(group1)

    if(n > 2){
      out <- vector('list',ng)

      for(i in seq_len(ng)){
        other <- perm.groups(setdiff(x,group1[,i]),n=n-1)
        out[[i]] <- lapply(seq_along(other),
                       function(j) cbind(group1[,i],other[[j]])
                    )
      }
    out <- unlist(out,recursive=FALSE)
    } else {
      other <- lapply(seq_len(ng),function(i) 
                  matrix(setdiff(x,group1[,i]),ncol=1)
                )
      out <- lapply(seq_len(ng),
                    function(i) cbind(group1[,i],other[[i]])
              )
    }
    out    
}
```

To show it works :

```
> perm.groups(1:6,3)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    4
[2,]    2    5    6

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    4
[2,]    2    6    5

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    5
[2,]    3    4    6

[[5]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    4
[2,]    3    5    6

[[6]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    4
[2,]    3    6    5

[[7]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    5
[2,]    4    3    6

[[8]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6

[[9]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    6    5

[[10]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    4
[2,]    5    3    6

[[11]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    5    4    6

[[12]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    5    6    4

[[13]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    4
[2,]    6    3    5

[[14]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    6    4    5

[[15]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    6    5    4
```

Comment: Awesome ! It seems to be working perfectly ! I'd spent a whole day on that without succeeding ! Thank you and Thanks to all of you dear stackoverflow readers !

Comment: You're welcome. You know that you can accept the correct answer by clicking the V-sign on the left of the post?

Comment: You've just taught me two things in less than 10 minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

here a solution based on the construction of splitter column.

```
x <- 1:4
a <- as.data.frame(t(combn(x,length(x)/2))
a$sum <- abs(rowSums(a)-mean(rowSums(a)))
lapply(split(a,a$sum),function(x) if(dim(x)[1]>2) 
                                      split(x,1:(dim(x)[1]/2)) 
                                   else 
                                      x)



$`0`
  V1 V2 sum
3  1  4   0
4  2  3   0

$`1`
  V1 V2 sum
2  1  3   1
5  2  4   1

$`2`
  V1 V2 sum
1  1  2   2
6  3  4   2
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I don't think the OP expects repetition. For example, in `1`, if it is `1, 2` then the other can be `3,4` or `4,3` but not `2,3` as `2` is already been "alloted". At least this is how I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute-force-and-dirty solution, which may work for different number of groups, but you really should test it before use. Moreover, as it uses `permn`, it will be unusable very fast depending on the size of your vector :

```
library(combinat)
split.groups <- function(x, nb.groups) {
  length.groups <- length(x)/nb.groups
  perm <- permn(x)
  perm <- lapply(perm, function(v) {
    m <- as.data.frame(matrix(v, length.groups, nb.groups))
    m <- apply(m,2,sort)
    m <- t(m)
    m <- m[order(m[,1]),]
    rownames(m) <- NULL
    m})
  unique(perm)
}
```

Which gives, for example :

```
R> split.groups(1:4, 2)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    3

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Or :

```
R> split.groups(1:6, 3)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5    6

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    6
[3,]    4    5

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    4    5

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    5
[3,]    4    6

[[5]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    4

[[6]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    3    4

[[7]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    4    6

[[8]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    3    6

[[9]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    3    5

[[10]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    5    6

[[11]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    3    5

[[12]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6

[[13]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    4    6

[[14]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    4    5

[[15]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    5    6
```

Comment: Why did you put `as.data.frame` in there?

Comment: @Roland In order to be able to sort each column independently. I told you it was dirty :)