# Optimization of a function which look for combination - out-of-memory trouble + speed

Tags: performance, r, memory, out-of-memory

Below is a function that creates all possible combination of splitting the elements of x into n groups (all groups have the same number of elements)

Function:

```
perm.groups <- function(x,n){
    nx <- length(x)
    ning <- nx/n

    group1 <- 
      rbind(
        matrix(rep(x[1],choose(nx-1,ning-1)),nrow=1),
        combn(x[-1],ning-1)
      )
    ng <- ncol(group1)

    if(n > 2){
      out <- vector('list',ng)

      for(i in seq_len(ng)){
        other <- perm.groups(setdiff(x,group1[,i]),n=n-1)
        out[[i]] <- lapply(seq_along(other),
                       function(j) cbind(group1[,i],other[[j]])
                    )
      }
    out <- unlist(out,recursive=FALSE)
    } else {
      other <- lapply(seq_len(ng),function(i) 
                  matrix(setdiff(x,group1[,i]),ncol=1)
                )
      out <- lapply(seq_len(ng),
                    function(i) cbind(group1[,i],other[[i]])
              )
    }
    out    
}
```

Pseudo-code (explainations)

```
nb = number of groups
ning = number of elements in every group
if(nb == 2)
   1. take first element, and add it to every possible 
       combination of ning-1 elements of x[-1] 
   2. make the difference for each group defined in step 1 and x 
       to get the related second group
   3. combine the groups from step 2 with the related groups from step 1

if(nb > 2)
   1. take first element, and add it to every possible 
       combination of ning-1 elements of x[-1] 
   2. to define the other groups belonging to the first groups obtained like this, 
       apply the algorithm on the other elements of x, but for nb-1 groups
   3. combine all possible other groups from step 2 
       with the related first groups from step 1
```

This function (and pseudo-code) was first created by Joris Meys on this previous post:
[Find all possible ways to split a list of elements into a a given number of group of the same size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753987/find-all-possible-ways-to-split-a-list-of-elements-into-a-a-given-number-of-grou)

Is there a way to create a function that returns a given number of randomly taken possible combinations ?
Such a function would take a third argument which is either percentage.possibilities or number.possiblities which fix the number of random different combinations the function returns.

Something like:

> new.perm.groups(x=1:12,n=3,number.possiblities=50)

Comment: Ummm...what if `nx` is not evenly divisible by `n`?

Comment: Also, if I've done my counting correctly ([which, it appears, I have](http://oeis.org/wiki/User:Peter_Luschny/SetPartitions#Partitions_with_equal_block_sizes)), there will be `(nb * ning)! / (nb! * (ning!)^nb)` such partitions. For relatively small values of `ning`, this will be larger than `(nb * ning)C(nb)` (ie the binomial coefficient `nb * ning` choose `nb`), which...yeah, that's gonna be big.

Comment: @JackManey yes, sorry I corrected my example. When nx%%n!=0 I get an error message.

Comment: The main problem is that storing all of these partitions is going to take up a **lot** of memory. I don't know what you're actually trying to accomplish, but if you could iteratively generate the partitions one at a time and then use them (without archiving them), that would probably stop you from running out of memory.

Comment: @JackManey Yes it your calculations seem correct ! the number of possibilities quickyl reach very high number ! I'll have enough CPU to calculate stuff but still I'd need to improve the calculation speed and the memory limitations

Comment: Well, if you want to limit the number of results, you can always take your input vector, scramble it (ie sort it randomly) and then fill the partitions via the new scrambled vector. If it isn't a partition that you've already seen, add it to your result set. Otherwise, scramble again and continue... That might not be the most efficient approach, but it's a hell of a lot better than trying to grab and store all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on @JackManey suggestion, you can sample one permutation group in an equiprobable fashion using

```
sample.perm.group <- function(ning, ngrp)
{
    if( ngrp==1 ) return(seq_len(ning))

    g1 <- 1+sample(ning*ngrp-1, size=ning-1)

    g1 <- c(1, g1[order(g1)])

    remaining <- seq_len(ning*ngrp)[-g1]

    cbind(g1, matrix(remaining[sample.perm.group(ning, ngrp-1)], nrow=ning), deparse.level=0)
}
```

where `ning` is the number of elements per group and `ngrp` is the number of groups.

It returns indices, so if you have an arbitrary vector you can use it as a permutation:

```
> ind <- sample.perm.group(3,3)
> ind
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    5
[2,]    3    7    6
[3,]    4    8    9
> LETTERS[1:9][ind]
[1] "A" "C" "D" "B" "G" "H" "E" "F" "I"
```

To generate a sample of permutations of size N, you have two options: If you allow repetitions, i.e., a sample with replacement, all you have to do is run the preceding function N times. OTOH, if your sample is to be taken without replacent, then you can use a rejection mechanism:

```
sample.perm.groups <- function(ning, ngrp, N)
{
    result <- list(sample.perm.group(ning, ngrp))

    for( i in seq_len(N-1) )
    {
        repeat
        {
            y <- sample.perm.group(ning, ngrp)

            if( all(vapply(result, function(x)any(x!=y), logical(1))) ) break
        }

        result[[i+1]] <- y
    }

    result
}
```

This is clearly an equiprobable sampling design, and it is unlikely to be inefficient, since the number of possible combinations is usually much larger than N.